# cannot run a jar in my Java Program, no result no error

Tags: java, jar, activemq-classic

I have an activeMq server and a listener for this server. In my listener I try to start a runnable jar file.

```
String[] args = new String[]{
    "java",
    "-jar",
    "HelloWorld.jar"};

try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
    Process p = pb.start();

    System.out.println("Start encrypt with: " + String.join(" ", args));

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

My HelloWorld.jar

```
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("/tmp/test/test.txt");
    file.mkdirs();      
}
```

}

If I write a queue in the server and the listener starts I can see the 'System.out.println("Start encrypt with*)'. With the command 'htop' I can see the processes, but the 'console.log' is not created.
Anybody an idea?

Sorry for the lame english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Thanks for the help. Without the help I had not find the answer.

The Problem was the the dependency-Entry in my pom.xml. 
I changed the entry from activemq-all to activemq-core and it worked.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The Problem was the spring-library in the activemq-all libs. there was a version crash.

Answer (score 0):

Input / Output redirection is a feature inherent to the command shell (cmd, bash, whatever). `java.exe` does not know about this. Instead, then Process started by your app gives you access to its InputStream and `OutputStream`.

So if you want the output written into console.log, you need to read your Process' `InputStream` and write in into `console.log` yourself.

First try it this way to make sure your reads are not blocking progress:

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
    Process p = pb.start();

    System.out.println("Start encrypt with: " + String.join(" ", args));

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I changed it. It is not importent for me that the streams are redirected. The problem is that the jar is not running. If I type the command in the cmd or bash it runs perfectly.

Comment: And that's the case even if you comment out all that stream-reading in your class? I'd think that might be blocking you.

Comment: What does that subprocess do? How do you check success and failure? If it IS running and you see the process- do you see passed parameters as well? Maybe environment is flawed and path to jar file is not found? Try absolute path to .jar maybe?

Comment: Thanks to u I found the solution. Thanks a lot.